# How much would it cost to craft a wand of scorching ray?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, pricing

I am planning to craft a wand of scorching ray for my imp familiar. Currently, I am a level 3 warlock//rogue. Since by the book this is **not** an item that exists, I wanted to get the accurate price for my DM.

> **Crafting wand**: You can create a wand of any 4th-level or lower spell that you know.
>    Crafting a wand takes one day for each 1,000 gp in its base price. The
>    base price of a wand is its caster level × the spell level × 750 gp.
>    To craft a wand, you must spend 1/25 of this base price in XP and use
>    up raw materials costing one-half of this base price. A newly created
>    wand has 50 charges.

and

> **Scorching ray (Sor/Wiz level 2)**: You blast your enemies with fiery
>   rays. You may fire one ray, plus one additional ray for every four
>   levels beyond 3rd (to a maximum of three rays at 11th level). Each ray
>   requires a ranged touch attack to hit and deals 4d6 points of fire
>   damage. The rays may be fired at the same or different targets, but
>   all bolts must be aimed at targets within 30 feet of each other and
>   fired simultaneously.

Following this, how do I calculate the price of wand of scorching ray for each variant (one ray, two rays, three rays)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have provided all the information, you just need to put it together. The following are the base or market price. If you are constructing the wand yourself, its 1/2 the total, unless the GM was to put some kind of premium on it. Also keep in mind that crafting items with higher caster levels than you posses has its own challenges.

One ray has a caster level (CL) of 3. So its formula is
$$3\times2\times750 = 4,500\text{ gp}$$

A two ray version has a CL of 7
$$7\times2\times750 = 10,500\text{ gp}$$

The three ray has CL of 11
$$11\times2\times750 = 16,500\text{ gp}$$

Don't forget to pay the XP.

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*scorching ray*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#scorching-ray) [evoc] (*Player's Handbook* 274) creates a number of rays per activation depending on the caster's level. The same applies to a *wand of scorching ray*: such a wand can be created at the typical minimum caster level of 3 up to caster level 6 so that it produces 1 ray per charge, at a caster level of 7–10 so that it produces 2 rays per charge, or at caster level 11 or higher so that it produces 3 rays per charge.

In all cases, the formula to determine the wand's market price is unchanged: 750(2 × X) gp where 2 is the spell level and X is the caster level. Thus a 1-ray *wand of scorching ray* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) has a market price of 4,500 gp; a 2-ray *wand of scorching ray* (2nd-level spell at caster level 7) has a market price of 10,500; and a 3-ray *wand of scorching ray* (2nd-level spell at caster level 11) has a market price of 16,500 gp.

To create these wands typically requires the feat [Craft Wand](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#craft-wand), a place to work safely, once per day access to the spell *scorching ray* each day that the craftsman's working on the wand, half the wand's market price in gp of raw materials, spending XP equal to 1/25 the wand's market price, and 1 day per 1,000 gp (or fraction thereof) of the wand's market price.

---

***Note:*** Sadly, the game sometimes substitutes the term base price *for the term* market price.